# Get PDF file from printer via Python scan instruction

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, scanning, printers

I need to send the scan instruction to the printer via Python and get the PDF file back. The standard Windows Paint program, for example, can send a scan instruction to any printer in the world, I need to do the same as Paint does only in Python, that is, I use a Pyhon function and it sends the instruction to mine printer she needs to scan and then the Python program takes the PDF scan back. Can you help me?

Example (something like this):

```
printers = list_my_pc_printers()

my_printer = printers[0]

scan_on_my_printer(my_printer, path_to_save_the_pdf_file)
```

My Structure:

- Windows 10 64x PC
- USB Commom HP Printer with Scanner

Comment: You might want to google for python scanner libraries, for example python-sane

Answer (score 4):

The only project I could find that supports Windows is [Libinsane](https://doc.openpaper.work/libinsane/latest/libinsane/index.html). It claims to work with Python, there is an [example](https://doc.openpaper.work/libinsane/latest/libinsane/howto_python.html) available. But I haven't tested it myself, and it looks like you have to build it from source for Windows.

For Linux, I would try out [Python Sane](https://pypi.org/project/python-sane/) which is a Python wrapper to access the [Sane](http://www.sane-project.org/intro.html) project. Sane [claims to support](http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html) a lot of different scanners. Again, haven't tested it myself, but the module has 40+ stars on Github, so it must work at least if you put some effort in.

Comment: Thank you for that, I tried getting libinsane up and running but it is proving challenging.

Comment: The insanity is in the name :') Maybe you have a raspberry pi lying around that you can try and set up with Sane?